How to set permission so that `du` can be run as some user on external drive directories that are owned by multiple other users?
I am trying to use the du command as one user from inside a docker container (Telegraf) to get the disk usage of various directories on an NFS-mounted external drive. My set up looks like this:

Both the docker containers run their services as the same user (monitor_usr:monitor_usr, UID/GID 1001:1001). The problem is essentially that all various files and directories on the external drive are created/managed by a variety of different users, and are therefore owned by different users. However, the du command requires executable permissions in order to get the correct disk size. The user monitor_usr doesn't own or have executable permissions on all the files created in the external drive by other users.
My thoughts:

I don't want to just chmod all files on the drive to allow all users access. I also don't think this approach would work anyway, because as new files are created on the external drive they would also need chmod after each creation.
I thought about creating a group (e.g. drive_usrgrp), with the intention of having all users that need to use the drive have full permissions. However, I think the issue would remain when new users (in other containers/VMs) create new files - they would again need to be chmod. Also, when I start the docker container currently with user monitor_usr:monitor_usr I would then have to start it something like monitor_usr:drive_usrgrp.

What's a good way to set these permissions up properly?

I think it may be sensible to allow "executable" bit (for "others") on directories. In any case, if it is a user mountable volume, why do you want to check the size? Or just make them to have a common group, or add the user which run du to all user group (but so it will be maybe similar to the first case, but disallowing cross-check between users). Your question is more about security, so you should find a good trade-off

@GiacomoCatenazzi 1) I can allow executable bit on directories, but then what happens when a user creates more directories/files on the drive with only r/w permissions (as done by their services)? I would have to go back in periodically and set the X bit again? 2) I want to monitor it because some of them contain backups and files which accumulate, and I want notifications, etc.

@GiacomoCatenazzi 3) can you elaborate on "add du user to all user groups" ? Do you mean inside the docker container, or on the host?

To me, it is not clear what do you mean with "external drives". Are disks that are mounted by user? Or just some network drives, etc.? -- In any case, it seems you are asking a common job: put a script in cronttab (as root), which monitor disk space and send warning (possibly just to admin, and admin will send a notification to users). And root has no problem on du. (but du is missleading, and what about hard-links?). or use quota and let system to handle it, per user.

@GiacomoCatenazzi my answers: 1) the drive is an NFS drive which is mounted automatically at boot with fstab, and should always be available. Its purpose is primarily for periodic backups. 2) the reason for having the telegraf container running the script is that its part of a larger monitoring system, with the benefit that metrics can be automatically piped into the Influxdb database. In addition, metrics can be graphed over time (the aim is not simply to receive a warning only). This is the reason for going this route, rather than using cron on the host as root or similar.

yeah. In theory influx should be to receive metrics (sent from other places), but sending data from host to image (in docker) is not always simple (from outside: "no problems"). But it doesn't matter where you execute the script (crontab, nodered, ...). Just take care of how do you mount the external disk in your image: you are root (in the image), so you have full access independent of user permissions (depending the mount/bind method in your docker)

@GiacomoCatenazzi it is simple to get data from host to image (I just bind mount the necessary directories, and bind mount the host proc file - this gives me everything I need). I am not root in the image, I am user "monitor_usr", which is achieved by passing in the "-u 1001:1001" argument to "docker run". This user does not have root privileges, so cannot execute du on the bind mounted directory.

@GiacomoCatenazzi one key piece of information (which i didn't realise was important) is that the drive is an NFS mounted drive, which has been exported from another machine. Not sure if it changes things?
